# Purpose of Community Wiki?

Tags: community-wiki, discussion

I am very confused as to the **true/original/intended** purpose of community wiki?  Based on my experience, questions are turned into community wiki on 'iffy' questions that are borderline allowed or somewhat-argumentative/subjective...I also have observed that questions with a lot of answers or will have a lot of answers are turned into CW...why is this?

*Can anyone inform me on the true purpose of CW, and why we use it, and what we intend by turning a post or question into a CW? Thanks!*

somewhat of a duplicate of [meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11740/](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/) … but looking more for the purpose of CW...

Comment: I'm not sure how this is different from the faq post you linked to

Comment: @Michael Reading the FAQ it is a bit confusing and technical. I think it needs to be "dumbed down" a bit. Also, it doesn't cover the **not** part of CW. I will try and update it over the weekend or early next week.

Comment: @Michael @Diago: the FAQ doesn't even attempt to say why one should use CW. eg is it to be used just to prevent rep gains on popular quesitons? (No.)

Comment: @Philip FYI. Multiple notifications do not work in comments.

Comment: @Diago I did not know that. maybe that's another one for `feature-request`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simple.

To allow anyone to collaboratively edit a question or answer. Since it's a combined effort no rep can be gained. Furthermore it requires less reputation to edit. All questions become CW after a certain amount of edits.

It is **not**

- An excuse to post subjective question
- An excuse to post polls
- A get out of jail free card for posting questions that does not meet the criteria for a specific site

Further information available in the FAQ [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

Comment: In particular, its primary purpose is collaborative effort, *not* removal of rep gain. People shouldn't demand CW to stop someone gaining rep, only to enable them to edit an answer.

Comment: @Philip Agreed. Do you feel I can improve my answer to indicate this better? If so, any suggestions?

Comment: you could make it CW and I could edit it directly :P but seriously, I think it's simple enough to say something like "making something CW is the poster's choice, not his duty". There's no situation I can think of where the same post could be allowed as CW but not as non-CW. However there are *some* who use CW to deflect rep gains from insanely popular questions, and if they want to do that they can. But it's not reasonable to demand others do it too.

Comment: @Philip And give up the opportunity to gain reputation. You gotta be kidding. This is the Wild Wild West. Every measly upvote helps :)